# LNK1104 error cannot open file enet.lib

Tags: c++, hyperlink, .lib, enet

I'm trying to make an online game using ENet and Cocos2d.

I defined the include folder and the libs as well everything is good for the server side and it compiled and working 100%. But when I tried to do the same for client side it gave me this really strange error:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'enet.lib'

Things I have already tried:

- checked if the lib and the include files really exist
- deleted the libs and the include folder and tried again
- restart VS2017 / Windows / Windows File explorer
- Checked the `.lib` file permission

etc...

Please Help me with this error its driving me crazy since yesterday..

Comment: You mention that you checked if the lib files exist, but did you check that the compilation process looks for the lib files in the correct directory?

Comment: Thanks for replying, How can i check ?

Comment: If by checking the VC++ Dir yes i did

Comment: 1) "_If by checking the VC++ Dir_" Which of VC++ Directories do you have in mind? There are several of those on property pages, did you check the correct one? 2) "_How can i check?_" Typically, one can use tools such as Process Monitor, to check which directories are searched, while trying to look for a particular file.

Comment: VC++ Dir that can be found in solution proprety and then Library dirs the path is well defined and exsist but while checking with Procces Monotior i found smthg important this:  *Operation: QueryOpen
*Result: NAME NOT FOUND
*Path: D:\COCOS2DX_Stuff\Projects\Brave_Solider\proj.win32\Lib\ent.lib   But its rly there even accessing with explorer is success

Comment: Oh man huge thanks this software helped me a lot thanks for your help the fault was the lib file name is enet and im refering to it as ent.lib quite stupid cant belive it took me one day to figure out actually, but thanks a lot ! how can i mark your comment as answer ?

Comment: "_how can i mark your comment as answer_" You can't, because it's a comment, not an answer. And I, myself, don't consider it as an answer, since it was merely a suggestion.